# Slashes got escaped in html append using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the result of my DOM

```
<div style="background: #fff url(" http:="" i.imgur.com="" qeoj4ae.png")="" no-repeat="" center="" center;"="">
```

what I did is like this :

```
var htmlBlock = '<div id="bannerWrap"  style="background: #fff url("'+image+'") no-repeat center center;">';
```

why the slash got escaped? I console console.log(image), the slash is there.. I wonder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : use `\'` to put images inside quotes.

```
var htmlBlock = '<div id="bannerWrap"  style="background: #fff url(\''+image+'\') no-repeat center center;">';
```

Comment: \ is to escape which symbol?

Comment: \ is to escape `'`, as your string is inside `' '` and to use single quote i.e. `'` inside string we have to use with \ like `\'`